# How can I pull only the messages from a pages Facebook wall using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, object

I'm trying to pull the content from the following Facebook page: https://graph.facebook.com/100000123344690/feed

I'm already pulling the data successfully using the following:

```
        $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/100000123344690/feed');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $wall = json_decode($response);

        var_dump($wall->data);
```

Now, i'm confused on how I loop over the $wall object and output the message param.  Can someone show me a simple loop outputting the message param?

Comment: What's the structure of `$wall->data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
foreach($wall->data as $post){
    echo $post->message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're pulling from facebook is json formatted data. you have to convert it to an array in order to loop through it.
You have to pass true to `json_decode` to decode it to a multidmensional array, try:

$wall = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($wall);